# php mysql query get value of a table with two different ID

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this table names MyLevels.

```
 id  | level | ParentLevelId
 ---------------------
 1   | basic | 1
 2   | silver| 1
 3   | gold  | 2
 4   | stone | 3
 5   | wood  | 2
```

on this table every level has a parent level. For example the `"gold"` level parent id is 2. It's mean the parent level is `"silver"`.
So I need a query to get the below in a html table:
Parent level comes from `ParentLevelId`.

```
level  | parent level | distance From Basic
-------------------------------------------
basic  | basic        | 0
silver | basic        | 1
gold   | silver       | 2
```

The distance from `basic` reference to the number that each level is far from `basic` level.
 
For example the `wood` level id is 5 and `5 - 1 = 4`. which means the it's 4 level far from `basic` level.
This is the only code I have:

```
$conn->prepare('SELECT id, level, ParentLevelId FROM MyLevels');
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have `name` and `bossId` got to do with `levelId` or `distansFromBasic`?

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry my bad. Updated the code.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Where do `levelName` and `distansFromBasic` come from?

Comment: Why does the output have `Basic` (with uppercase `B`) when that doesn't appear in the input?

Comment: @Barmar just typo error. corrected now. Please read it again.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. Where do those results come from? Is `levelId` the ID of the parent?

Comment: Read http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Barmar I have updated it. Please take a look and let me know if it make sense now. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table with itself to get the name of the parent level from the parent ID. Join it again to get the ID of the `basic` level, so you can subtract the ID from that.

```
SELECT m2.level, m1.level AS parentLevel, m2.id - m3.id AS distanceFromBasic
FROM MyLevels AS m1
JOIN MyLevels AS m2 ON m1.id = m2.parentLevelId
CROSS JOIN MyLevels AS m3
WHERE m3.level = 'basic'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/961f65/3)

Comment: Thanks, Worked fine

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ml1.level,
    (
        SELECT
            ml2.level
        FROM
            MyLevels AS ml2
        WHERE
            ml2.id = ml1.ParentLevelId
    ) AS parentLevel,
    (
        SELECT
            ml1.id - ml2.id
        FROM
            MyLevels AS ml2
        WHERE
            ml2.level = 'basic'
    ) AS distanceFromBasic
FROM
    MyLevels AS ml1;
```

Just keep in mind this only works if that column is the primary key or is unique and that column is being used as the parentID.

Comment: Where is `distanceFromBasic` in your query?